# What software can be used to create high quality GIF images?

Tags: software-recommendation, animation, gif

[image]

Does anyone know what software is best to create high quality GIF images?  I do not know if this kind of GIF can be created in Photoshop?  If Photoshop cannot be used what type of software is recommended to complete an high quality GIF?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know if this animation was made in Photoshop, but you can do it in Photoshop. If you open up the GIF and take a look in the `Timeline` panel, you will see that the smoothness of the animation was achieved using a high framerate (30fps, 254 frames).

[image]

The animation also uses 246 out of the 256 possible colors.

So it is possible to make a GIF animation in Photoshop that looks like this, but at the price of a filesize of **1,7 MB**.

Comment: how to add the bounce Animation

Answer (score 1):

This was probably done in photoshop using the new timeline animation panel. You can read up all about it at Adobe's help page: http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-timeline-animations.html

Comment: how to add the bounce Animation

Comment: The bounce is easing. you can fake easing in photoshop, it is easier to do in after effects though.